# how to validate select2 multiple option in jquery

Tags: jquery

select2 jquery, this is my output:

```
$('.select3_multi').select2({ placeholder: "Select Multiple", allowClear: true}).change(function(){
    $('.select3_multi').valid();
});
```

html source:

```
<select class="select3_multi form-control" multiple="multiple"  name="test[]" id="test"  tabindex="-1"style="width:335px!important" class="required">
    <option value="">Select Test</option>
</select>
```

Comment: help me thanks advanced

Comment: hello sir help me

Comment: you can use events provided by them. `https://select2.github.io/options.html#events`

Comment: this not wotking properly

Comment: this working like first select one after remove this then validate is comming

Answer (score 1):

Wrap your select box with a form and add validator rules.

```js
$("#myform").validate({
  rules: {
    'test[]': {
      required: true
    }
  },
  messages: {
    //messages
  }
});
$('.select3_multi').select2().change(function() {
  $(this).valid();
}).valid();
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/css/select2.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.16.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/select2/4.0.3/js/select2.js"></script>

<form id="myform">
  <select class="select3_multi form-control" multiple="multiple" name="test[]" id="test" tabindex="-1" style="width:335px!important" class="required">
    <option value="">Select Test</option>
  </select>
</form>
```